# 3 queries sum not equal to exact of total doc count in a database?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have 3 scenarios-

1. Get total docs count of all docs with element name `xyz` and `abc`. In this case I also require element name's values. Like, for example, doc count of docs where element name `xyz` value is `lala` and element name `abc` value is `lili` and so on for all possible values/ combination of `xyz` and `abc`. Both elements should exist in a doc.
2. Get total docs count of all docs with element name `xyz` and element `abc` does not exist in that doc. In this case I need doc count of docs for all possible values of `xyz` value wise.
3. Get total docs count for docs that do not contain element `xyz`.
   Together these 3 on addition should be equal to total doc count of database.
   **Note:** The database size is huge. The query has to be fast. I can slightly compromise on precision. I need to avoid wildcard search. Help.

   `xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:and-query(( cts:element-query(xs:QName("meta:xyz"), cts:true-query()),cts:element-query(xs:QName("meta:abc"), cts:true-query())
                             )) )
                    )`.

This is returning different results then when I sum up all possible values obtained from `cts:value-tuples` and pass 1 by 1 to -

```
let $x := local:get-doc-count-for-localname-source(cts:value-tuples((
          cts:element-reference(xs:QName("meta:xyz")),
          cts:element-reference(xs:QName("meta:abc"))
          )) ) 
let $y := fn:sum(($x))
return xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:and-query((                
                cts:element-query(xs:QName("meta:xyz"), cts:true-query()),
                cts:element-query(xs:QName("meta:abc"), cts:true-query())
                      )) )
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, the universal index can yield fast estimates by passing a query to `cts.estimate()` in Server-Side JavaScript or to `xdmp.estimate()` in XQuery.

An estimate of documents containing both FIRST_ELEMENT and SECOND_ELEMENT:

```
cts.estimate(
  cts.andQuery([
    cts.elementQuery('FIRST_ELEMENT', cts.trueQuery()),
    cts.elementQuery('SECOND_ELEMENT', cts.trueQuery())
  ]))
```

An estimate of documents containing FIRST_ELEMENT but not SECOND_ELEMENT:

```
cts.estimate(
  cts.andQuery([
    cts.elementQuery('FIRST_ELEMENT', cts.trueQuery()),
    cts.notQuery(
      cts.elementQuery('SECOND_ELEMENT', cts.trueQuery())
      )
  ]))
```

An estimate of documents not containing FIRST_ELEMENT:

```
cts.estimate(
    cts.notQuery(
      cts.elementQuery('FIRST_ELEMENT', cts.trueQuery())
      )
  )
```

An estimate of all documents in the database:

```
cts.estimate(
  cts.trueQuery()
  )
```

Hoping that helps,

Comment: I need doc counts element-value wise. I would want to choose cts:element-value-query and pass 1 by 1 all possible values and there sum should match with what you are trying to do.

Comment: In that case, substitute cts.elementValueQuery() calls for the cts.elementQuery() calls above.  Note that you can pass multiple values in a single cts.elementValueQuery() call.

Comment: @ehennm - cts:element-value-query was not giving accurate results. I chose to use cts:element-range-query and this time the accuracy is good enough.